# IDE Error ocurred Android Studio 3.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxSZI.png) [Loading Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CLtU.png) [Code of the activity main drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbpgS.png)

Greetings, after updating my Android Studio to the version 3.1, I have a problem with the menu section (Navigation Drawer), the preview is not working and it throws an error "IDE error ocurred". When I click on the error icon residing at the right bottom corner of my IDE, I get the following:

```
null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.getRenderResult(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:602)
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenViewBase.getResult(ScreenViewBase.java:109)
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenView.getResult(ScreenView.java:30)
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.menu.NavigationViewSceneView.getPreferredSize(NavigationViewSceneView.java:64)
        at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.SceneView.getPreferredSize(SceneView.java:95)
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.createSceneViewsForMenu(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:265)
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.doCreateSceneView(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:234)
        at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.createSceneView(SceneManager.java:73)
        at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.<init>(SceneManager.java:66)
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.<init>(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:157)
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.NlDesignSurface.createSceneManager(NlDesignSurface.java:145)
        at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.DesignSurface.setModel(DesignSurface.java:281)
        at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.initNeleModelOnEventDispatchThread(NlEditorPanel.java:143)
        at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.lambda$null$4(NlEditorPanel.java:139)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.lambda$smartInvokeLater$7(DumbServiceImpl.java:366)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: the same thing happened to me. my menu is not drawing and this exception I found inside my log file

Comment: here is my exception log picture guys: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6pk9.png

I try deleting ~/.android and ~/.AndroidStudio3.0 --- invalidate cache and restart --- creating new application with new IDE version [NONE OF THEM WORKED] still have the problem

Comment: I've already tried all that, and it has not worked for me either. I have reinstalled Android Studio a total of 5 times, the next time I do it I will also delete the SDK to make a totally empty installation.

Comment: did deleting the SDK work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem.

I copied the source code from the file activity_main_drawer.xml and deleted it.

So, I created a new "Menu resource file" with the same name (activity_main_drawer.xml) and put inside it the source code that I had copied.

It worked for me...